# detect triangle from square.c

Tags: c, opencv

I'm working a project using opencv. I want to detect shape from a webcam. I already succes to detect square by edit square.c, and now I want to use square.c to detect triangel.

Is it possible to detect triangle from square.c?
which part that I have to add or modify?

**edit**

i've tried adding this code:

```
else if ( result->total == 3 &&
    fabs ( cvContourArea(result, CV_WHOLE_SEQ)) > 1000 &&
    cvCheckContourConvexity(result))
{
    s = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
    {
        if (i >= 1)
        {
            t = fabs( angle(
                      (CvPoint*)cvGetSeqElem(result, i),
                      (CvPoint*)cvGetSeqElem(result, i-1),
                      (CvPoint*)cvGetSeqElem(result, i-2)));
            s =  s > s ? s : t;
        }
    }
}
```

bu the result is, the triangle detected on the square..

Comment: Please ask a specific, programming related question.

Comment: show and explain, what you have tried so far.

Comment: @PeterMiehle I've tried adding an `if` on the result of `cvApproxPoly` but the result is program detects that the square = triangle.

Comment: The condition `s > s` will always be false.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg I've change to `s > t`, but still same result.

Answer (score 0):

be i = 1: with

```
...
(CvPoint*)cvGetSeqElem(result, i),
(CvPoint*)cvGetSeqElem(result, i-1),
(CvPoint*)cvGetSeqElem(result, i-2)));
```

you access elements 1, 0 and the last element of the sequence. Is that intended?

second: why

```
for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
{
    if (i >= 1)
```

why not

```
for (int i = 1; ...
```

Answer (score 0):

You might also consider having a look at one of my [previous answers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9857379/951860) on detecting many triangles in an image.

Here is the primary function to pay attention to in that example:

```
vector<Point> getAllTriangleVertices(Mat& img, const vector< vector<Point> >& contours)
{
    vector<Point> approxTriangle;
    vector<Point> allTriangleVertices;
    for(size_t i = 0; i < contours.size(); i++)
    {
        approxPolyDP(contours[i], approxTriangle, arcLength(Mat(contours[i]), true)*0.05, true);
        if(approxTriangle.size() == 3)
        {
            copy(approxTriangle.begin(), approxTriangle.end(), back_inserter(allTriangleVertices));
            drawContours(img, contours, i, Scalar(0, 255, 0), CV_FILLED);

            vector<Point>::iterator vertex;
            for(vertex = approxTriangle.begin(); vertex != approxTriangle.end(); ++vertex)
            {
                circle(img, *vertex, 3, Scalar(0, 0, 255), 1);
            }
        }
    }

    return allTriangleVertices;
}
```

Essentially this function uses contours detected by `findContours` and draws the triangle vertices on the image as well as fills them.

Hope that helps!